# Rudimentary Computer Vision Techniques for Python Bot.

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, bots

After completion several chapters in computer vision books I decided to apply those methods to create some primitive bot for a game. I chose [Fling](http://www.miniclip.com/games/fling/en/) that has almost no dynamics and all I needed to do was to find balls. Balls may have 5 different colors and also they can be directed to any of 4 directions (depending on eyes' location). I cropped each block in the field such that I can just check each block whether it contains a ball or not. My problem is that I'm not able to find balls correctly.

[image]

My first attempt was following. I sum RGB colors for each ball and get [R, G, B] array. Then I sum RGB colors for each block in the field. If block's array has a similar [R, G, B] as ball's array I suggest that this block has a ball. 
The problem is it's hard to find good value for 'similarity'. Even different empty blocks vary in such sums significantly.

Second, I tried to use *openCV* module that has **[matchTemplate](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html)** function. This function matches image with another source image and along with *minMaxLoc* function returns a value *maxLoc*. If maxLoc is close to 1 then the image is probably in source image. I made all possible variations of balls (20 overall), and passed them with the entire field. This function worked well but unfortunately it sometimes misses some balls in the field or assigns two different types of balls (say green and yellow) for one ball. I tried to improve the process by matching balls not with the entire field but with each block (this method has advantage that it checks each block and should detect correct number of balls in the field, when matching with entire field only gives one location for each color of ball. If there are two balls of the same color matchTemplate loses information about 2nd ball) . Surprisingly it still has false negatives\positives.

Probably there is much easier way to solve this problem (maybe a library that I don't know yet) but for now I can't find one. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Do you have the exact match of the background (The green field)?

Comment: I think you may be overcomplicating this a bit by bringing in external computer vision libraries. For telling apart ball and non-ball, I'd experiment more with task-specific pixel-twiddling. Besides the average colour channel values I think it would be useful to consider the sharpness of the transitions (e.g. grass-to-ball and ball-to-eye should be easy to detect). Once you're certain that you have a ball, it should be easy to find the colour of the ball by sampling pixels in the center (and comparing with known ball colours).

Comment: As far as task-specific pixel-twiddling goes, since you can generate "all possible variations of balls" and you can do pixel-perfect alignment of the tiles (the balls seem to always be in the center of a tile when you're to make a move), I think simply comparing the percentage of pixels almost equal to the aligned ones in a reference picture would get you very far. (The numbers are so small that I expect performance is not likely to be a problem here, even with a fairly naive solution.)

Comment: @IanMedeiros You mean field without balls?

Comment: @svk What is the task-specific pixel-twiddling? And how to find transitions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The balls seem pretty distinct in terms of colour. The problems you initially described seem to be related to some of the finer, random detail present in the image - especially in the background and in the different shading/poses of the ball.

On this basis, I would say you could simplify the task significantly by applying a set of pre-processing steps to "collapse" the range of colours in the image.

There are any number of more principled ways to achieving accurate *colour segmentation* (which is what, more formally, you want to achieve) - but taking a more pragmatic view, here are a few quick'n'dirty hacks.

So, for example, we can initially smooth the image to reduce higher frequency components...

[image]

Then, convert to a *normalised RGB* representation...

[image]

Before, finally posterizing it with the [mean shift filtering step](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#pyrmeanshiftfiltering)...

[image]

Here is the code in Python, using the OpenCV bindings, that does all this in order:

```
import cv 

# get orginal image
orig = cv.LoadImage('fling.png') 

# show original 
cv.ShowImage("orig", orig)

# blur a bit to remove higher frequency variation
cv.Smooth(orig,orig,cv.CV_GAUSSIAN,5,5)

# normalise RGB
norm = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(orig), 8, 3) 
red = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(orig), 8, 1) 
grn = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(orig), 8, 1) 
blu = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(orig), 8, 1) 
total = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(orig), 8, 1) 
cv.Split(orig,red,grn,blu,None)
cv.Add(red,grn,total)
cv.Add(blu,total,total)
cv.Div(red,total,red,255.0)
cv.Div(grn,total,grn,255.0)
cv.Div(blu,total,blu,255.0)
cv.Merge(red,grn,blu,None,norm)
cv.ShowImage("norm", norm)

# posterize simply with mean shift filtering
post = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(orig), 8, 3) 
cv.PyrMeanShiftFiltering(norm,post,20,30)
cv.ShowImage("post", post)
```

Comment: Last picture looks just fantastic.

Answer (score 3):

Your task is simpler in several respects than the ones the general computer vision algorithms you'll find were designed for: you know exactly what to look for and you know exactly where to look for it. As such I think involving an external library is an unnecessary complication, *unless* you're already familiar with it and can use it effectively as a tool to solve your own problem. In this post I will only use PIL.

First, distinguish the task into two simpler tasks:

- Given a tile, determine whether there's a ball there.
- Given a tile where we're pretty sure that there's a ball, identify the colour of the ball.

The second task should be simple and I won't spend time on it here. Basically, sample some pixels where the ball's main colour will be visible and compare the colours you find to the known ball colours.

So let's look at the first task.

First off, note that the balls don't extend to the edge of the tiles. Thus you can find a fairly representative sample of the *background* of a tile, whether or not there's a ball there, by sampling the pixels along the edge of the tile.

A simple way to proceed is to compare every pixel in a tile with this sample of the tile background, and to obtain some sort of measure of whether it's generally similar (no ball) or dissimilar (ball).

The following is one way to do this. The basic approach used here is to calculate the mean and the standard deviation of the background pixels -- separately for the red, green, and blue channels. For every pixel, we then calculate the number of standard deviations we are from the mean in every channel. We take this value for the most dissimilar channel as our measure of dissimilarity.

```
import Image
import math

def fetch_pixels(col, row):
    img = Image.open( "image.png" )
    img = img.crop( (col*32,row*32,(col+1)*32,(row+1)*32) )
    return img.load()

def border_pixels( a ):
    rv = [ a[x,y] for x in range(32) for y in (0,31) ]
    rv.extend( [ a[x,y] for x in (0,31) for y in range(1,31) ] )
    return rv

def mean_and_stddev( xs ):
    mean = float(sum( xs )) / len(xs)
    dev = math.sqrt( float(sum( [ (x-mean)**2 for x in xs ] )) / len(xs) )
    return mean, dev

def calculate_deviations(cols = 7, rows = 8):
    outimg = Image.new( "L", (cols*32,rows*32) )
    pixels = outimg.load()
    for col in range(cols):
        for row in range(rows):
            rv = calculate_deviations_for( col, row, pixels )
            print rv
    outimg.save( "image_output.png" )

def calculate_deviations_for( col, row, opixels ):
    a = fetch_pixels( col, row )
    border = border_pixels( a )
    bru, brd = mean_and_stddev( map( lambda x : x[0], border ) )
    bgu, bgd = mean_and_stddev( map( lambda x : x[1], border ) )
    bbu, bbd = mean_and_stddev( map( lambda x : x[2], border ) )
    rv = []
    for y in range(32):
        for x in range(32):
            r, g, b = a[x,y]
            dr = (bru-r) / brd
            dg = (bgu-g) / bgd
            db = (bbu-b) / bbd
            t = max(abs(dr), abs(dg), abs(db))
            opixel = 0
            limit, span = 2.5, 8.0
            if t > limit:
                v = min(1.0, (t - limit) / span)
                print t,v
                opixel = 127 + int( 128 * v )
            opixels[col*32+x,row*32+y] = opixel
            rv.append( t )
    return (sum(rv) / float(len(rv)))
```

A visualization of the result is here:

[image: Ad-hoc ball recognition]

Note that most of the non-ball pixels are pure black. It should now be possible to determine whether a ball is present or not by simply counting the black pixels. (Or more reliably: count the size of the largest single blob of non-black pixels.)

Now, this is a very ad-hoc method and I certainly don't make any claim that it's the best method. The "limit" value was determined by experimentation -- essentially, by trial and error. It's included here to illustrate the sort of method I think you should be exploring, and to give you a starting point to tweak from. (If you want a place to start experimenting, you could try to make it give a better result for the top purple ball. Can you think of weaknesses in the approach above that might make it give a result like that? Always keep in mind, however, that you don't need a perfect-looking result, just one that's good enough. The final answer you want is "ball" or "no ball", and you just want to be able to answer that reliably.)

Note that:

- You need to make sure you take the screengrab when the balls have finished rolling and are lying still in the center of their tiles. This simplifies the problem immensely.
- The game's background affects the problem -- if there are ocean-themed or desert-themed levels coming up, you will need to test and possibly tweak the recognizer to make sure it still reliably works.
- Special effects and/or GUI elements that cover the playing field will complicate the problem. (E.g. consider if the game has a 'cloud' or 'smoke' effect that sometimes floats over the playing field.) You may want to tweak the recognizer to be able to return "no result" if it's not sure -- then you can try another screengrab later. You may want to take several screengrabs and average the results.
- I have assumed that there are only balls and non-balls. If later levels have other kinds of objects, you will have to experiment more to find out how to best recognize those.
- I haven't used the 'reference picture' approach. However, if you have an image containing all the objects in the game and you can exactly align the pixels with your tiles, that's likely going to be the most reliable approach. Instead of comparing the foreground to the sampled background, compare the foreground to a set of known foreground images.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the elaborated answer. Second, just curious how you calculated size of one tile? I ask because I had hard time trying to find right pixel of the border for the original image in Paint.net. And last and more important, as I understand in the last function you go pixel by pixel computing dr, dg, db which are some sort of similarity for each color (btw, why it has this form? I mean fraction) than you compare it to the max deviation (limit), and if it's not similar you make it brighter. I don't understand what is 'span' and what the function returns?